# Nesting functions in JavaScript and variable scope?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I have a function where variables are declared within that function and I need to make another function that will use those variables and will run when I click a button on a HTML doc, do I create a nested function and call that, if so how?

Comment: Good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: you can bind to the button from within the outer function, or poke the variables through to globals and call them directly from html attribs.

Comment: Type all your variables as `window.variableName`, and you can use them anywhere. It's great!

Comment: @Barmar It's a good article but I still don't know how to call it with an 'onclick'?

Comment: @Barmar:dont try to kill him.haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function outer(some_var) {
  function inner() {
    alert(some_var);
  }
  document.getElementById("my_button").onclick = inner;
  // or
  document.getElementById("my_button").addEventListener("click", inner);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JAVASCRIPT:

```
   function MyFunction_outer(){
    var local variable1=some_value;
    var MyFunction_inner=function(some_value){
    alert(some_value);
      }
    }
```

HTML:

```
//this is how call a function onclick.

      <div onclick="MyFunction_outer" >CLICK_ME</div>//for outer function
      <div onclick="MyFunction_inner" >CLICK_ME</div>//for inner function
```

This is how you call a function.
You can also use **addEventListener** if you dont want to write inline code and pollute your HTML code.

**Using addEventListener-:**

```
document.getElementById('button_id').addEventListener("click",function({MyFunction_outer()},false)
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('button_id').addEventListener("click",function({MyFunction_inner()},false)
```

Comment: He wants to put the inner function in the `onclick`, not the outer function.